# Take a single line input of numbers, and storing it into an array

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner, user-input

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class HistogramChart
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Please enter the population of data: ");
      int populationOfData = scan.nextInt();

      System.out.println("Please enter data separated by spaces: ");
      String data = scan.next();

      int indexWhiteSpace = data.indexOf(" ");

      int[] dataArray = new int[populationOfData];
      int tempInt = 0;

      for(int index = 0; index < populationOfData; index++)
      {
         String tempString = data.substring(0, indexWhiteSpace);
         data = data.substring(indexWhiteSpace+1, data.length());
         tempInt = Integer.parseInt(tempString);

         dataArray[index] = tempInt;
         indexWhiteSpace = data.indexOf(" ");
      }
      System.out.println(dataArray[0]);   
   }
}
```

I realize there's nothing yet to print out the entire array, as i'm just trying to get it to print anything, but this is continually printing the following errors:

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1954)
    at HistogramChart.main(HistogramChart.java:22)
"
I cannot figure out why this is saying this. 
Please help!

Comment: It says so because you are trying to access something outside the boundaries of the array. Without looking at your code, please help yourself by debugging this. Put a breakpoint and step through and see where it crashes.

Comment: Scanner.Next() will only return the first word. This means that data.IndexOf(" ") will be -1, giving you the SystemIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not using split ?

```
class HistogramChart {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Please enter data separated by spaces: ");
      String data = scan.nextLine();

      String tmpDataArray[] = data.split(" ");

      int dataArray[] = new int[tmpDataArray.length];
      for (int i = 0; i < dataArray.length; ++i) {
          dataArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(tmpDataArray[i]);
      }
}
```

Comment: i'm in first year CS so i'm not entirely sure what split is, what would that do exactly?

Comment: I provided to split the parameter " " which is a blank space, so it will place into an array every word that is separated by a " "

Comment: oh okay! from there I could then create a method to parse the string array into an integer array could I not?

Comment: Edited my post, this way you have your integer array

Comment: Wow that makes complete sense! Okay thank you!, It's been a long week... haha

Comment: No problem ;) mark the thread a solved by checking the green cross at the left of the most helpfull answer so people can refer to it

Answer (score -1):

If I remember correctly, using

```
 String data = scan.next();
```

Like you're doing, you will just scan a single element. Try using scan.nextLine() so that it takes the whole line, and then split by spaces so you get an array of your data. And the problen it is actually giving you is because you look for `indexOf(" ")` but since you're not reading a full line, that nevers happens and you get a -1. When you try to look for a substring with the index -1, then you get that error.

Comment: this makes complete sense, but everytime i tried it with the scan.nextLine() it skips the input and just carries on with the code.

Comment: You need to go down one line. Use scanner.nextLine() after nextInt(), and then save the next line. Check the code out in IDEONE: http://ideone.com/8UOhhF